# API documentation pages match some site names incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, documentation

The bug is not in the API itself, but in the pages documenting its methods. To reproduce, follow the link http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=default&site=math and observe that the page shown pertains not to *Mathematics* site but to *Mathematics Educators*.

The above link was generated with the *Link* tool after selecting *Mathematics* as the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console JS was doing fuzzy matching on `?site`; but that's not really correct, as you demonstrated.

With the latest deploy it does an exact match if possible.